# Parsing XML document using .Descendents(value)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml document that I have created. However `xml.Descendants(value)` doesn't work if `value` has certain characters (including space, which is my problem).

My xml is structured like this:

```
<stockists>
  <stockistCountry country="Great Britain">
    <stockist>
      <name></name>
      <address></address>
    </stockist>
  </stockistCountry>
  <stockistCountry country="Germany">
    <stockist>
      <name></name>
      <address></address>
    </stockist>
  </stockistCountry>
  ...
</stockists>
```

And my C# code for parsing looks like this:

```
string path = String.Format("~/Content/{0}/Content/Stockists.xml", Helper.Helper.ResolveBrand());
XElement xml = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(path));

var stockistCountries = from s in xml.Descendants("stockistCountry")
                                select s;

StockistCountryListViewModel stockistCountryListViewModel = new StockistCountryListViewModel
{
    BrandStockists = new List<StockistListViewModel>()
};

foreach (var stockistCountry in stockistCountries)
{
    StockistListViewModel stockistListViewModel = new StockistListViewModel()
    {
        Country = stockistCountry.FirstAttribute.Value,
        Stockists = new List<StockistDetailViewModel>()
    };

    var stockist = from s in xml.Descendants(stockistCountry.FirstAttribute.Value) // point of failure for 'Great Britain'
                   select s;

    foreach (var stockistDetail in stockist)
    {
         StockistDetailViewModel stockistDetailViewModel = new StockistDetailViewModel
         {
             StoreName = stockistDetail.FirstNode.ToString(),
             Address = stockistDetail.LastNode.ToString()
         };

         stockistListViewModel.Stockists.Add(stockistDetailViewModel); 
     }

     stockistCountryListViewModel.BrandStockists.Add(stockistListViewModel);
 }

 return View(stockistCountryListViewModel);
```

I am wondering if I am approaching the Xml parsing correctly, whether I shouldn't have spaces in my attributes etc? How to fix it so that Great Britain will parse

Comment: Describe "doesn't work" please. This looks basically OK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It fails on the line commented, saying that space is not allowed

Comment: I see now, but what was that supposed to do? It's looking for a `<Great Britain> </Great Britain>` element.

Comment: @HenkHolterman But it fails because it has a space in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However xml.Descendants(value) doesn't work if value has certain characters

`XElement.Descendants()` expects an XName for the *tag*, not for the *value*.

And XML tags are indeed not allowed to contain spaces.

Your sample XML however only contains a value for an attribute, and the space there is fine.

Update:

I think you need

```
//var stockist = from s in xml.Descendants(stockistCountry.FirstAttribute.Value) 
//              select s;

var stockists = stockistCountry.Descendants("stockist");
```